# How to continuosly play Background Music in LOOP

Tags: objective-c, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I want Continuously Background Music in my one of level, I am looping my Audio File like Following Ways :

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"mymusic.mp3"  loop:YES];
```

& I also tried This way :

```
[[CDAudioManager sharedManager] playBackgroundMusic:@"AirRaidSirens.mp3" loop:YES];
```

I guess it should continuously play in loop While loop:YES But its not working.

I also tried By preloading my sound effect.But,its not working by Both ways.I dont know why!.. Please help.

Comment: not working in that it doesn't play any music, or doesn't loop the music? If it's not even playing the mp3 then it may be in an unsupported format, or simply not added to the project.

Comment: it was not playing in Loop But Now it has been solved as i was stopping my background music in some other class.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use OALSimpleAudio for music and sound effects inside my projects. It always works and if you try to loop or preload you can do with few code.

```
//access audio object
OALSimpleAudio *audio = [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance];
// play background sound
[audio playBg:@"your-file-name.mp3" loop:TRUE];
```